# Why does ffmpeg ignore protocol_whitelist flag when converting https m3u8 stream?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am attempting to download and convert an m3u8 stream to mp4 using ffmpeg. The command I first tried was

```
ffmpeg -i MIE.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto MIE.mp4
```

*(see below for contents of `MIE.m3u8`)*

This failed immediately with error

```
[https @ 0x7fb419607d40] Protocol 'https' not on whitelist 'file,crypto'!
MIE.m3u8: Invalid argument
```

(Note that the memory address changes each time.)

I discovered the `-protocol_whitelist` flag and appended `-protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto` to my command

```
ffmpeg -i MIE.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto MIE.mp4
```

but this still resulted in the same error.

Why does `ffmpeg` appear to ignore the `protocol_whitelist` flag and parameters?

---

`MIE.m3u8` (which I managed to fetch from the [website](http://www.nhk.or.jp/eigo/mission/?das_id=D0005140255_00000) I am trying to scrape video from) looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=508000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2"
https://nhk-vh.akamaihd.net/i/das/D0005140/D0005140255_00000_V_000.f4v/index_0_av.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBdrl8GX2UAVyUXA1tF7MYlFTbSF88WtA7oAMDksTsiVdAKPuuREVfi8iXMsOWFp6eQU2sk6dnE9g%3d%3d
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=47000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
https://nhk-vh.akamaihd.net/i/das/D0005140/D0005140255_00000_V_000.f4v/index_0_a.m3u8?null=0&id=AgBdrl8GX2UAVyUXA1tF7MYlFTbSF88WtA7oAMDksTsiVdAKPuuREVfi8iXMsOWFp6eQU2sk6dnE9g%3d%3d
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[`protocol_whitelist`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#Protocol-Options) is a parameter only on the `input` file (in your case, `MIE.m3u8`), so it must be specified *before* the input in your command.

Specify `-protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls` prior to `-i` and it'll work as you expect:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -i MIE.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc MIE.mp4
```

You can a similar case on a [Debian Bugs discussion board](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=857369), and read up more on the [syntax](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis) of ffmpeg commands.